# Dragula: how to make the object follow the cursor

Tags: javascript, dragula

I am using Dragula and I am trying to make the object I am dragging follow my cursor. How would I go about doing this.

EDIT: Maybe it is worth noting what the html here looks like:

```
<div>
  <paper-menu id="listL">
     <template id="left" is="dom-repeat" items="{{leftList}}">
       <div>
         <custom-polymer-element></custom-polymer-element>
       </div>
     </template>
  <paper-menu>
<div>
```

I initialize dragula by calling the ready function inside of Polymer:

```
Polymer({
  is:"wapper-element",
  ready: function() {
    var drake = dragula([this.$.listL]), {
      revertOnSpill: true,
    });
});
```

EDIT2:
Here is an image of what I see when I try to drag something:

[image]

What is in the bottom left is what I see every time, when I am dragging an image, and it stays there, regardless of where I drag the element. There is no element there or anything, the text just appears there.

EDIT3:

**Solution**:

The cause of the problem was that I was not importing dragula.css correctly. If anyone else encounters this problem I would recommend ensuring you have imported dragula.css and done so correctly.

Comment: By default what you are dragging does follow your cursor. I am not sure what you are asking?

Comment: Whenever I drag an object, I see the object replicated in the mirrorContainer, but the object does not follow my cursor.

Comment: OK you want the actual element to move around, not the mirrored guy it creates?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Can you show the config you are initializing dragula with?

Comment: I have added the html of the container I am dragging from as well as how I initialize dragula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this. The best you can do with simple config is using:

```
removeOnSpill: true
```

This will remove the element being dragged from the container when it leaves the container it is over.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/e95nqyf9/1/

I am not even sure you can fake it using events like setting `display: none` when dragging starts on that element because the mirror is a clone so whatever styling you apply to one is mirrored on the other.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/e95nqyf9/

Essentially at the end of the day what is following your cursor is the original element in some ways, just a clone of it.

Comment: My problem is that I do not even see anything being dragged when I move my cursor, all I see is a ghost element appear when I hover over another valid container and then another copy of the image which is the mirrorContainer image which is set to document.body by default.

Comment: @Ulsting if you can create a fiddle and reproduce the issue I can help but as you can see in first fiddle I have in answer you can see the element I am dragging around clearly.

Comment: @Ulsting also I have seen this happen before when the CSS from dragula is not included. Are you sure it's being correctly included?

Comment: I am getting it from the same dist folder that I am getting the dragula.js from

Comment: @Ulsting if you look at the source of your code in the browser do you see that CSS there? Try searching for gu-mirror

Comment: Yes, I do see it in the sources tab.

Comment: Ok. Well if you can reproduce this issue in a jsfiddle I can help but at this point I can't see what you are seeing.

Comment: All of the code I have, more or less, is in the question statement now.

Comment: I have added a picture of what I see when I try to drag something.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. If each list in there is a draggable portion that is what I would expect to see exactly.

Comment: Have you looked at my first jsfiddle?  Thats the same thing that happens in mine. You do see something when you are dragging it seems. I am not sure you are explaining the issue you perceive correctly. First you said you see nothing. Now you say you just see the text but all you would see is the text since thats all the element really has.

Comment: You were in fact correct earlier when you said it was a problem with dragula.css. I was importing it, however, I was importing incorrectly. This fixed the issue.

Comment: Great, glad to hear you its fixed!